# python: getting keys of a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, key

When I do dict.keys() in python3, I do not get a list, but an object of class dict_keys. Why is this and what can I do with this object? How to get the list?

Example code: `type(dict(sape=4139, guido=4127, jack=4098).keys())`
I wonder if this result is intentional and why?
I called matplotlib.plot(d.keys(),....) and got an error.

Comment: You can iterate over it. You can convert it to a list using `list(...)`. You could see what functions and attributes it has with `dir(...)`. You can see its documentation with `help(...)`. You can do a million things with it, really.

Comment: Thanks for the dir() and help() !

Answer (score 6):

`dict.keys` returns a `dict_keys` object, which is an iterable object.

So, you can either convert it to a list using:

```
keys = list(dict.keys())
```

Or, you can simply iterate over the `dict_keys` object, like it was intended:

```
for key in dict.keys():
    print(key)
```

In your example, it will print out:

```
sape
guido
jack
```